# Finding percent contamination of sulfur dioxide in air by redox reaction with iodine

Tags: physical-chemistry, redox, ideal-gas

I would really like some help with this problem. My work is at the bottom. I've tried multiple ways and have gotten the same answer for both, but for some reason the computer program won't accept the answer as it is. Any help is appreciated!

> An environmental engineer analyzes a sample of air contaminated with sulfur dioxide. To a $\pu{500 ml}$ sample at $\pu{700 torr}$ and $\pu{38 ^\circ C}$, she adds $\pu{15.50 ml}$ of $\pu{0.01017 M}$ aqueous iodine, which reacts as follows (equation 1 is unbalanced):
>
> $$\ce{SO2(g) + I2(aq) + H2O(l) → HSO4−(aq) + I−(aq) + H+(aq)}\tag1$$
>
> Excess $\ce{I2}$ reacts with $\pu{11.37 ml}$ of $\pu{0.0105 M}$ sodium thiosulfate (equation 2 is unbalanced):
>
> $$\ce{I2(aq) + S2O3^2−(aq) -> I−(aq) + S4O6^2−(aq)}\tag2$$
>
> What is the volume % of $\ce{SO2}$ in the air sample?

---

Here's my work and answer:

Find the number of moles of $\ce{I2}$:

$$  0.01550 \times 0.01017 =\pu{1.576 \times 10^{-4}mol} $$

number of moles of $\ce{S2O3^2-}$:

$$0.01137 \times 0.0105=\pu{1.1938x10^-4 mol}$$

excess $\ce{I2}$:

$$1.1938 \times 10^{-4} \times \frac{1}{2}=\pu{5.969x10^-5 mol}$$

number of moles of $\ce{I2}$ in reaction with $\ce{SO2}$:

$$1.576\times10^{-4} - 5.969 \times 10^{-5} = \pu{9.791x10^-5 mol}$$

$$9.791\times10^{-5} \times \frac{2}{1} = \pu{1.9582x10^-4 mol} $$

$$V=\frac{(1.9582 \times 10^{-4})(0.082)(311.15)}{0.921}= \pu{5.425 ml}$$

$$\frac{\pu{5.425 ml}\,\ \ce{SO2}}{\pu{500 ml}\, \text{air}}\cdot (100\%) = 1.085= \pu{1.09 vol.\% }$$

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry! For formatting, See [here](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/443/which-symbols-are-written-in-roman-upright-font-and-which-are-italicized) and [here](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here?noredirect=1&lq=1). For a more detailed MathJax guide, look [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), [minor other details](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3044/hidden-points-of-editing-you-probably-didnt-know?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: @Safdar - Thanks for making the problem readable. Very nice edit!

Comment: @ User. Why do you show an equation that is unbalanced ? What is the meaning of the words "the computer program won't accept the answer" ? Which computer program ? Is it to understand that the program obtains another result ? How far away from yours ?

Comment: Please try to find a descriptive title for your question. While being as concise as possible, it shall indicate, without ambiguity, the subject matter of the question in such a way as to distinguish it from that of other questions, without going into unnecessary detail.

Comment: It is good practice to stay with general algebraic expressions as long as possible, plugging in the numbers in the last minute. This way it is much easier for authors and readers to either verify the correctness either spot errors or mistakes.

Comment: Your problem is you didn't balance any equation. You correctly use mole ratio for second equation. But, mole ratio for first is 1:1 (if you balance it).